# Keep the state or value of a DropDownChoice and TextField both inside a ListView

Tags: scala, wicket

I have implemented a listView and every time that a new item is added in this ListView the values inserted in the textField and selected in a DropDownChoice are lost.

The following pictures show what's happen before and after add a new ListView item:

[image: ListViewBefore]

And after Add a new item:

[image: ListViewAfter]

I'm implemented the code bellow:

```
  var listData = workSheetDAO.listWorkSheetUser(selectedUser, beginDate, endDate)

  var lbPeriodTotal = new Label("periodTotal")
  lbPeriodTotal.setOutputMarkupId(true)
  add(lbPeriodTotal)

  add(new ListView[WorkSheet]("listWorkSheet", listData) {

    override protected def onBeforeRender() {
      super.onBeforeRender()
    }

    def populateItem(item: ListItem[WorkSheet]) = {
      var workSheet = item.getModelObject()

      item.add(new LinkDate("initDate", workSheet, 1))
      item.add(new LinkDate("endDate", workSheet, 1))

      item.add(new TextField("description"))

      val listCustomer: java.util.List[Customer] = customerDAO.listCustomers

      item.add(new DropDownChoice("customerSelection", listCustomer, new ChoiceRenderer[Customer]("id")))

      if (workSheet.endDate == None) {
        item.add(new Label("total", ""))
      } else {
        var period = new Period(workSheet.initDate, workSheet.endDate.get)
        periodTotal = periodTotal.plus(period)
        lbPeriodTotal.setDefaultModel(new Model(periodTotal.toPeriod().normalizedStandard().toString(getFormatter())))
        period = period.normalizedStandard()
        item.add(new Label("total", period.toString(getFormatter())))
      }         

   } 
}

private class LinkDate(id: String, workSheet: WorkSheet, type: Int) extends Link[String](id) {

  setEnabled(false)
  add(new Label("label", new Model[String]() {
    override def getObject(): String = {
      var result = ""
      if (type == 1) {
          result = workSheet.initDate.toString("dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss")
      } else 
          result = workSheet.endDate.toString("dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss")
      return result
    }
  }))

  def onClick() {}
}
```

The only values preserved are the values of the labels.

Please, someone could help me, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you add new item to the List you refresh it, so all not saved values will be lost.
In your case would do the following:

First, save data on change (onblur/onchange or with button 'save').

Second, bind description and customerSelection on populating, like so:

```
new TextField("description", new PropertyModel(obj, "description"))
new DropDownChoice("customerSelection", new PropertyModel(obj, "customer"), listCustomer, new ChoiceRenderer[Customer]("id")))
```